# How to Store multiple values in single field laravel

Tags: php, json, angular, laravel

I am using these simple form and want to save multiple data at a single time how it is possible?

**controller**

```
  $status= new PostTable();
  $status->language = $request->language;
```

**blade**

```
<input type="checkbox" value="hindi" name="language[]" id="language"> Hindi
```

**model**

```
protected $fillable = [
  'language'
 ]
```

Comment: you can insert comma seperated values or json encoded data

Comment: 'language' => json_encode($language) i have tried like these but it's not working out.!

Comment: amit i want to retirve data how to do it.?

Comment: Just fetch the value and use json_decode for it. Like json_decode($language)

Comment: oh,yes but i am using right now 
```controller
        $status = PostTable::where('id',$id)->get();
        return view('post.profile', compact('status'));
```

Comment: oh,yes but i am using right now 
```controller
        $status = PostTable::where('id',$id)->get();
        return view('post.profile', compact('status'));
```

Comment: On view you can use json_decode($language) and use foreach to echo each value

Comment: okay,amit but want to know about controller side how to compact data,means of query

Comment: i did it,        
$status = PostTable::get();
return view('post.profile', ['status'=>$status]);

Comment: Yes you have done correctly

Comment: please mark my answer as accepted if it does help you out

Answer (score 1):

Storing Array is not allowed inside **mysql DB**

so You can convert it to **json** and do that

```
$status->language = json_encode($request->language);
```

or

```
$status->language = implode(',', $request->language);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can insert comma
implode(",",$request['language'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you need to do it in your controller

```
$status= new PostTable();
$language[] = $request->language
$status->language = json_encode($language);
```

Answer (score 1):

**please chnage your code becuase you are select multiple language so use `implode` function**

```
 $status->language = $request->language;
```

**CHANGE**

```
 $status->language = implode(',', $request->language);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here in from $request->language is an array.In php you gave a function **implode()** .The implode function in PHP is used to "join elements of an array with a string".So try This

```
$status->language = implode(',', $request->language); //in which how you want separte your array is the first param
```

It will save your multiple data separate by a comma.For details: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/051e29/implode-and-explode-function-in-php/

Answer (score 1):

use [serialize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function

```
$status->language = serialize($request->language);
```

you can unserialize later to use .

```
unserialize($request->language)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This method for multiple values:

```
 $user = User::find(auth()->user()->id);
 $categoriesString = implode(",", $request->get('categories'));
 $user->categories = $categoriesString;
 $user->save();
```

For Multiple Images:

```
$medical_record = [];
$image = $request->file('file_name');
if ($image) {
    foreach ($image as $files) {
        $destinationPath = storage_path('medical-records/');
        $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . uniqid() . $files->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $files->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);
        $medical_record[] ="$profileImage";         
    }
    $data['file_name'] = implode(",", $medical_record);
}
```